# How much power does a dedicated graphics card consume when only the integrated card is used?

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics, intel-hd

My desktop machine has an Intel i5 CPU with integrated graphics and a dedicated geforce card. Through blacklisting the nvidia driver in Linux and by using two cables, I'm planning to use the integrated intel card for Linux and the dedicated Nvidia card for Windows. Since  the whole idea is to consume less power when using Linux, I was wondering if anybody knows how much power the dedicated card will consume when it's not initialized and whether it might be necessary to unplug the power cable from it to really save on power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a discrete card will draw around 5W of power, which can be anything from 10-25% of the total power consumption of your laptop. The exact amount will depend on the model, you can check it typung `sudo powertop` on a terminal.